# Gin serve []byte as file

Tags: http, go

I have a golang backend with gin. Its supposed to work as a proxy for a ftp server that contains audiofiles. So my client should be able to call the endpoint /download/filepath the Golang application is then supposed to fetch the file from a ftp server and return it as a file(no stream).

My current solution is to read the file from the ftp as []byte and temporarily write it to disk with ioutil.TempFile() and return that file with ctx.File().

If possible I would like to skip the step where I'm creating a tempfile. Is that possible? Perhaps theres a way to proxy the call and directly connect the http call to the ftp call?

Note I don't control the client application so I can't change it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [Context.Data](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Data) to write a `[]byte` as the response.

You can also use [Context.DataFromReader](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.DataFromReader) to copy directly from the FTP response to the HTTP response.

HTTP responses are a stream of bytes. There's no way to get around that.

Comment: I can't accept you answer because I don't have enough reputation. But it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Gin framework, to serve binary files to client then the browser automatically downloads the file when the user hits the API, and the server doesn't need to save the file (There isn't static file), then use this method [c.Data](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Data). Where the data type of the third parameter is []byte. Here is the example code.

```
func DownloadFile(c *gin.Context) {
    byteFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./file.txt")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    c.Header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=file-name.txt")
    c.Data(http.StatusOK, "application/octet-stream", byteFile)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write to the `ResponseWriter` as you are reading the file. It works just like using `http.ResponseWriter`.

```
import "io"

//...

io.Copy(ctx.ResponseWriter, ftpReader)
```

Comment: Which is essentially using some sort of stream. But that's just how it works I guess.